# overlay background pdf page to background color

Tags: backgrounds

What I want to do:

1. Fill background color as yellow!30.
2. Fill background.pdf over the page with a 2mm border as yellow!30 and others as background.pdf.

Current code the fill color covered the whole page and background.pdf cover the whole page as well!

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  total={8.50in,11.00in},
  left=30mm,
  top=18mm,
}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.75}
\setlength{\parindent}{4ex}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.2in}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
%
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\ULCornerWallPaper{}{background.pdf}
%
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow!30}
\vspace*{60px}
\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont
%
Hello world!\par
%
\end{document}
```